# Cross Platform Serial Output

Tags: serial-port, cross-platform

I'm trying to figure out the best option for a cross platform way of writing a small script to send some data over a serial port. Seriously, it will probably only need to be 10-20 lines. However, I really would love to have it be redistributable to Mac, Windows and Linux without having to install any platforms or runtimes. 
The main option I've been looking into was python since it should already be on Mac and Linux and I could maybe use py2exe for windows. I would still provide the raw script for Windows in case they already have it.

Are there any better options? All I have to do is get the current system time and time zone, do some minor manipulation and send about 10 bytes out to whatever COM port is needed (probably provided as a command line argument by the user).

Answer (score 0):

I know you talking about a script, but I think Java suits better because the RE is installed on most computers (Win, *Nix and I think on Macs too). Also there should be no need to adjust code for getting the system time and time zone on different systems. For the access of COM ports I know they can be written like regular files on Windows and Linux (e.g. echo HELLO>com1 or echo HELLO>/dev/com1). This could be the command line argument then.
Hth, Philipp

Comment: Hmmm... maybe I'll just try the write to file version. I trust Java less and less these days.

Comment: Did you have success with the write to file version?

Answer (score 0):

Real Studio would work fine for a task such as this.  It has a built-in Serial class and creates native executables from single source code for Windows, OS X and Linux. No run times required.

http://www.realsoftware.com